Convergence of quotient of sample variance and sample mean
Let $(X_k)$ be a collection of i.i.d random variables with finite fourth moment satisfying $\mathbb{E} X = 0$ and $\mathbb{E} X^2 = 1$.
What can be said about the convergence of the following quotient
$$ \frac{\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k^2 - 1)\right)^2}{\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_i\right|}$$
in the limit as $n \to \infty$? By convergence, I mean almost surely, in probability, or in law.
Here are a few examples of what I have in mind. If $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X = - 1) = \frac{1}{2}$, then the quotient is almost surely $0$. If we consider the two-dimensional random walk with steps $(X_k, X_k^2 - 1)$, then by the recurrence of random walks, we can always construct subsequences $(n_j)$ such that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n_j} (X_k, X_k^2 - 1) \to (a,b), \ j \to \infty , $$
where $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are possible(accessible) values of the random walk. For such subsequences, it follows that the quotient vanishes as $j \to \infty$.
Using a similar idea with the central limit theorem, I think that we can show that the quotient converges to $0$ in law, and thus also in probability.
In all of these examples, we can simultaneously control the terms in the quotient, and the investigation of the limit is possible.
Are the there examples where the quotient diverges, or fails to converge? Otherwise, is there a general way to prove that this quotient is always vanishing almost surely.

I don't think almost sure convergence to $0$ should hold. Here's the intuition: take iid standard Gaussian $X_i$s. Then I can write the object of interest as  $ K_n := \frac{(R_n^2 - n)^2}{nR_n} \cdot \frac{1}{|\langle 1, \mathbf{\Theta_n}\rangle|}$, where $R_n^2$ is $\chi^2_n$-distributed, $\Theta_n$ is uniform on the $n$-sphere, and $R_n$ and $\Theta_n$ are independent. Back of the envelope, $(R_n^2 - n)^2$ is typically of size $n$, while $nR_n$ is typically of size $n^{3/2}$. So, roughly, if $|\langle \mathbf{1}, \Theta_n\rangle| < 1/\sqrt{n},$ then $K_n > c$ for some $c$.

(contd.) By some angle chasing, this occurs with probability roughly $1/n$ (since $|\mathbf{1}n| = \sqrt{n}$). Now, if we just consider the subsequence $K{ n \log n},$ then due to the increased gap between terms, there should be significant mixing, so that each $K_{n \log n}$ is roughly independent, and the probability that $K_{n \log n } > c$ is roughly $1/n\log n.$ Since $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n} = \infty,$ $K_{n \log n}$ should be larger than $c$ infinitely often. Making this formal might be quite painful, though, I don't see an obvious clean route.

I believe that your quotient converges in distribution.
But I think it is possible to have to write a paper for answering your question. Here (theorems 2.1, 2.2,...,2.7 and section 3)  are the asymptotic distribution of these similar (and relatively
simpler) ratios $$T_n = \frac{\sum_k X_k^2}{\left(\sum_k X_k\right)^2}$$ and $$C_n = \frac{\sum_k X_k^2}{\sum_k X_k}$$ and the results are already very complex.
